# Error when booting Mac with FileVault Encryption

Tags: filevault, encryption

Ever since I encrypted my MacBook Pro I am seeing this error right after I type in my password at the initial screen.

Any ideas what this means, how serious it is or maybe even how to fix it?

[image]

[Larger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xppPQ.jpg)

Apologies for the smudginess and reflection in the pic - it's displayed for a fraction of a second and it's the best one I've managed to take.

Answer (score 2):

What is really is might be a bit of a guessing game, but the next step is clear.

Boot to your Recovery HD and see what disk utility makes of the volume itself.

If you lack a Recovery HD - then it's time to make a back up of any files you can reach (attach the drive to a sled / boot in target mode / install the OS to an external drive and copy things off using another OS.)

At that point, you can re-run the installer which may fix the issue for you and will certainly get you back to having an Recovery HD or expose a hardware problem if you can't even re-instal the OS on top of the data that is there.

Comment: Unfortunately, for whatever reason I have no Recovery HD to choose. There's only OSX drive and that's it. I'm on the latest stable Lion.

Comment: I did run the Disk Utility from Lion though. There were few permissions wrong which it fixed, the volume verification went alright, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: And - without a recovery HD - it begs the question: How exactly are you encrypting your disk? I had assumed FileVault - but I might be answering what to do when FileVault fails - not what you've managed to change with some other encryption tool.

Comment: Yes, it is File Vault encryption. I think I've had a Recovery HD before I encrypted the drive, but I'm not entirely sure. Anyway, the OS seems stable, but any Error is not good hence my question. I do have a Time Machine backup and another Carbon Copy Cloner backup so I am "insured" for a drive fail. I think I'll look at installing the OS from scratch and restoring the files from backup. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Btw. I find it interesting that the error messages have typos - *coundn't* - that's not Apple-like.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every typo, grammar error and whatnot that exists in the API, console logs, man pages, etc... Now - it's rare for one to get to a dialog box or something that users normally see.

Answer (score 0):

When the system disk is filevaulted, you will not see Recovery HD in the boot menu (pressing alt during boot). Try holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> during the boot (press the combination immediately after you hear the Apple chord if you didn't disable it). 
More information is available here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718

Answer (score -1):

It's just some image files that are missing, so I'd say not too serious.